# Call String from Activity to another

Tags: android, android-activity, onesignal

I would like to call a String from an Activity to another. It is not a simple as normal calling but this calling happens when I open a notification.
I have a notification open handler that store the strings. I want to call the value stored in the strings **title** and **body** Here is the code of the open handler.

```
 public class MyNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
// This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
private Context mContext;
public MyNotificationOpenedHandler (Context context) {
   mContext = context;
}
@Override
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
    OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
    JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
    String title = result.notification.payload.title;
    String body = result.notification.payload.body;
    String launchUrl = result.notification.payload.launchURL; // update docs launchUrl

    String customKey;
    String openURL = null;
    Object activityToLaunch = AboutActivity.class;

    if (data != null) {
        customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
        openURL = data.optString("openURL", null);

        if (customKey != null)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);

        if (openURL != null)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL to webview with URL value: " + openURL);
    }


    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, (Class<?>) activityToLaunch);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("openURL", openURL);
    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "openURL = " + openURL);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

The main question how can I call the strings **title** and **body** in other activities

Comment: `intent.putExtra()` doesn't work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bundle or put extra immediately:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, (Class<?>) activityToLaunch);
intent.putExtra("title", title);
intent.putExtra("body", body);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

In the next activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
String body = intent.getStringExtra("body");
```

if the structure is complicated, you can use bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("title", title);
bundle.putString("body", body);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

If the data is needed to be global variable to whole application,
you can extend [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) and implement getter and setter for these data.

Also, you can put the title and body to Database or [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), and read it from any activity you want. Just make sure that do not do the i/o task in UI thread.